# unity -- object references, why do I always get errors?

Tags: unity

For context:

I randomly generate a few points on the map, and each point is a gameobject with a script containing an OnMouseDown method. Here's the relevant pieces of code(I've omitted the irrelevant parts to make it easier to read).

```
    public class MouseClick : MonoBehaviour {
    public static string clickedWaypoint;
    void Awake(){
        nWM = gameObject.AddComponent<NavigateWorldMap>();

    }
    public void OnMouseDown(){
        clickedWaypoint = gameObject.name;

        Player.updatePlayerPosition();          

    }
    }
```

I also have a Player game object in my scene with the player script attached:

```
public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    private Transform playerTransform;
    private GameObject waypointObj;


    void Start(){
        chooseStartingLocation();
    }
    private void chooseStartingLocation(){
        int number = Random.Range(0,WorldMapPoints.waypointNumber);
        transform.position = GameObject.Find ("waypoint"+number).GetComponent<Transform>().position;

    }

    public static void updatePlayerPosition(){
        waypointObj = GameObject.Find (MouseClick.clickedWaypoint);


    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Assets/Scripts/Player.cs(19,17): error CS0120: An object reference is required to access non-static member `Player.waypointObj'
```

Which is really confusing to me since I can't see anything wrong with what I wrote and this is the first time I encountered this error. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Jeesh man, why do you use AddComponent to add scripts? Refer to your other question please.

Comment: Double click the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error here is that you're addressing a non-static variable, with a static method.

I recommend you take a time-out of Unity, and get to know better non-static vs static variables, and non-static vs static methods. I will recapitulate in a bunch of words and explain it to you roughly though.

So the non-static variable here is `waypointObj`. As you can see in the error message,  "An object reference is required to access non-static member Player.waypointObj". The **static** method `updatePlayerPosition()` is trying to call a variable that is not specific to the **class** but is a variable related to every **instance** of the class.

The fix here would be to whether make your method non-static, or to make the variable waypointObj static. Choose any of these according to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out with my other question. I would do the same thing I did previously but this situation seems to be a little different. If I make my method non-static, won't I have to add that script to my waypoint objects? The problem is, that script is the player script -- so I'll end up with ~20 copies of the player script on each waypoint object.

Comment: Like I said, you can make your method non-static, or the variable you are addressing static. I don't know anything about your game, so it's your choice to choose which solution of these two to use. The answer I provided solves your issue.

Comment: :( i never realized that I didn't set waypointObj to static. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, glad I solved your problem. Kindly mark answered questions as answered if you no longer have any more questions to ask.